# Can we customize SharePoint audit reports? How to add new custom columns to SharePoint audit reports?

Tags: auditing, spaudit

Can we customize SharePoint audit reports? I want to add new custom columns to SharePoint audit reports. I want to show version history comment in SharePoint audit reports. How to add new custom columns to SharePoint audit reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only to the extent that the UI allows you to select different options. The audit data itself cannot be customized.

Comment: Thanks Trevor.Yes I found that we can not customize audit data OOTB.